# Logstash HTTP output can't post to to HTTPS endpoint requiring client certificates

Tags: ssl, nginx, logstash, filebeat, pkcs#8

I'm currently attempting to send some sample events from Logstash receiving servers on our production environment to a testing env via the http output.
The server on the receiving end is a custom Nginx HTTPS endpoint which accepts post data (endpoints for both single events, and bulk events to support Elasticsearch bulk indexing format) and places it into a redis queue, which is eventually read by Logstash processing servers.

The current http output on the logstash receiving server looks something like this:

```
 http {
   url => "https://json-logs-endpoint.example.com:8443/event"
   http_method => "post"
   format => "json"
   ssl_certificate_validation => false
   client_cert => "/etc/filebeat/ssl/filebeat.crt"
   client_key => "/etc/filebeat/ssl/filebeat.key"
   cacert => "/etc/filebeat/ssl/filebeat.chain"
 }
```

The cert related options are using the same files as the filebeat log shipper (installed on all servers), via elasticsearch output.  The permissions on the files in `/etc/filebeat/ssl/` does allow logstash to read the certs. My filebeat config ressembles something like this:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors: []
  registry_file: "/var/lib/filebeat/registry"
  config_dir: "/etc/filebeat/conf.d"
output:
  elasticsearch:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
    - json-logs-endpoint.example.com:8443
    protocol: https
    path: "/multi-event"
    tls:
      certificate_authorities:
      - "/etc/filebeat/ssl/filebeat.chain"
      certificate: "/etc/filebeat/ssl/filebeat.crt"
      certificate_key: "/etc/filebeat/ssl/filebeat.key"
```

All filebeat instances on all servers are successfully sending data via https to this Nginx server, via the `/multi-event` endpoint.

The only difference between the `/event` and `/multi-event` endpoints are that the former accepts a single JSON event and the latter accepts data in the format of an [elasticsearch bulk indexing request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).
Both endpoints are secured via SSL in the same fashion.  When Logstash is started, there's no indication of any error relating to the http output, although after a very short period of time pipeline essentially halts.  Running logstash in verbose mode then provides a bit more information, with [this stack trace](http://pastebin.com/ZsFURE2M).

I'm guessing the problem is related to the format of the provided certs?  I would really appreciate if someone could point out my issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the problem was due to the fact that the client key file specified in the http output:

```
client_key => "/etc/filebeat/ssl/filebeat.key"
```

should have been in a **PKCS8** format.  Once I ran the following command to convert it to the proper format:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in '/etc/filebeat/ssl/filebeat.key' -out '/etc/filebeat/ssl/pkcs8-filebeat.key'
```

and then updated the client_key parameter to point to the PKCS8 formatted key:

```
client_key => "/etc/filebeat/ssl/pkcs8-filebeat.key"
```

This solved the issue and the HTTPS POST requests are no functioning as expected.  Hopefully this ends up being useful to someone else in the future.