# Logstash HTTP output with SSL certificates not working on Ubuntu 14

Tags: ssl, openssl, logstash

The Logstash HTTP output when used for SSL authentication doesn't seem to be working on Ubuntu 14, but works perfect in Ubuntu 16. 
Referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138900/logstash-http-output-cant-post-to-to-https-endpoint-requiring-client-certificat), I have compiled it with pkcs8 format of the key, and the same certificate and the same key works fine in Ubuntu 16, but not on Ubuntu 14. I am getting the error "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" on Ubuntu 14, Any ideas on what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my Ubuntu 14 had Java 1.7, which had some deprecated cipher suites, which was why I was getting an handshake failure while connecting to the server. It works fine in Java 1.8. You can provide custom Java to the logstash process by specifying JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/JRE bin/logstash conf.d/logstash.conf.